# AWS CodePipeline: how to find out if deployment stage's ECS Fargate task is finished executing proccesses in containers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

I have a AWS CodePipeline with two deployment stages:

1. Deployment to ECS Fargate task (test environment).
2. Deployment to ECS Fargate task (actual environment).

First deployment stage (test one) has container with entry point which executes tests.

My problem is that I'd like to proceed to second deployment stage only if first (test) fargate task has finished all proccesses in containers and stopped them.

So far I've tried moving first ECS Fargate task's launch to buildspec.yml with command 'aws ecs run-task', which gets up, does the job and then kills itself, which is behaviour that is needed. However I'd like to stop whole pipeline until tests are not finished.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://medium.com/@timothyhaydenhawkins/adding-feature-tests-to-your-aws-codepipeline-86c2af35f5fa) says you can deploy your containers on the build machine itself using docker-compose as a `prebuild` action, then in `build` action run the test runner command (npm test). This should fail the `deploy test` stage if the tests fail and pass if the tests pass and then let the pipeline continue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one more stage for Approval in between TestDeploy and Deploy stage.

1. The pipeline stops when it reaches the approval action. If an Amazon SNS topic ARN was included in the configuration of the action, a notification is published to the Amazon SNS topic, and a message is delivered to any subscribers to the topic or subscribed endpoints, with a link to review the approval action in the console.
2. An approver examines the target URL and reviews comments if any.
3. Using the console, CLI, or SDK, the approver provides a summary comment and submits a response:

   - Approved: The pipeline execution resumes.
   - Rejected: The stage status is changed to "Failed" and the pipeline execution does not resume.

If no response is submitted within seven days, the action is marked as "Failed."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it's possible to have some endpoint/subscriber configured to automatically catch SNS messages?

Comment: Yes, In the SNS topic you will be configuring subscribers and you will use the sns topic ARN in the approval action of core pipeline. Please refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_SetupSNS.html) link for more details about configuring SNS.